# Google play console - spam policy issue

Tags: android, web, google-play

I have recently published a webview application in google playstore. My app has been rejected and I received a mail that said "***We don’t allow apps whose primary purpose is to drive affiliate traffic to a website or provide a webview of a website without permission from the website owner or administrator***." It was our web-dev team that developed the website. How do I proceed further. What is the format of the document that states the permission given by the website owner?

I tried to communicate with someone in play console help center. But couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File an appeal, and provide proof of ownership of the website, although they don't specify what kind of proof they might be looking for. I have a print of Google Search console domain verification and several screenshots from my hosting dashboard on Firebase. It worked in my case.